# Make scrollbar change length dynamically on Canvas tkinter

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I've created a program in Python where i request some HTML through an urllib2 call and I print it on a Canvas item.

HTML source code is quite long so I tried to add a scrollbar to my canvas, but this one doesn't appear when the text is printed

Is there a way to make Scrollbar change dimension dinamically detecting the text lenght? Thank you in advance

This is my source code:

```
from tkinter import *
import urllib.request

def getURL():
    canvas.delete("all")

    with urllib.request.urlopen(entry.get()) as response:
        received_html = response.read()
    print(received_html)
    canvas.create_text(10,0,text=received_html, anchor=NW, width=700)

#Widget and item initialization
browser_window = Tk()
browser_window.geometry('900x700') # Size 900, 700
frame = Frame(browser_window) #frame
frame.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=5)
label = Label(frame, text= 'Inserisci URL:')
entry = Entry(frame)
canvas = Canvas(frame) #canvas
scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=canvas.yview) 
#Scrollbar on my canvas


entry.insert(END, "http://jesolo.it")
#canvas configure
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set, background='#ffffff', 
scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

button = Button(frame, text='Vai', command=getURL )



label.pack(side=TOP)
entry.pack(side=TOP)
button.pack(side=TOP)

scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y) #Scrollbar pack
canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=5) #Canvas config
scrollbar.config(command=canvas.yview)

browser_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why are you using a canvas, rather than the Text widget which is much more suited to displaying long text?

Comment: Because I would like to add other items like buttons, entries, and I can't do that on a text widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you add the text to the canvas, you need to update the `scrollregion` attribute so that the canvas knows how much of its virtual space should be scrollable.

```
def getURL():
    ...
    canvas.create_text(10,0,text=received_html, anchor=NW, width=700)
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
```

Comment: I tried now, thank you very much now it's working. I've looked for every possible solution on the internet, but what I was missing is that i should've updated the scrollregion after i create the text, not before. I'm really thankful for your help